# jQuery formatting negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a local weather site through freecodecamp.  I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to assign jQuery to show parenthesis around negative numbers.  i.e. when it is -5 degrees I am trying to get it to say (-5).

Here is the jQuery I am currently working with...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var long;
            var lat;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;

            var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=79b001616877b59c717616181ee219ec";

            $.getJSON(api, function(info) {
                var farh;
                var cels;
                var kelvin;
                var tempMin;
                var minTemp;
                var tempMax;
                var maxTemp;
                var tempMinC;
                var minTempC;
                var tempMaxC;
                var maxTempC;
                var strF = ("\u00B0'F'");
                var tempSwitch = false;
                kelvin = info.main.temp;
                farh = Math.round((kelvin) * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
                cels = Math.round(kelvin - 273);
                tempMinC = info.main.temp_min;
                minTempC = Math.round(tempMinC - 273);
                tempMaxC = info.main.temp_max;
                maxTempC = Math.round(tempMaxC - 273);
                tempMin = info.main.temp_min;
                minTemp = Math.round((tempMin) * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
                tempMax = info.main.temp_max;
                maxTemp = Math.round((tempMax) * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
                var city = info.name;
                var weatherInfo = info.weather[0].description;
                var forecastLow = minTemp;
                var forecastHigh = maxTemp;
                var forecastLowC = minTempC;
                var forecastHighC = maxTempC;
                var currCond = info.weather[0].icon;
                $('#farh').html(farh);
                $('#city').html(city);
                $('#weatherInfo').html(weatherInfo);
                $('#forecastLow').html(forecastLow);
                $('#forecastHigh').html(forecastHigh);
                $('#currCond').html(currCond);
                $('#switch').click(function() {
                    if (tempSwitch === false) {
                        $('#farh').html(cels);
                        $('#forecastLow').html(forecastLowC)
                        $('#forecastHigh').html(forecastHighC)
                        tempSwitch = true;
                    } else {
                        $('#farh').html(farh);
                        $('#forecastLow').html(forecastLow);
                        $('#forecastHigh').html(forecastHigh);
                        tempSwitch = false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="weather-header" id="city"></h2>
    <h1><span class="curr-temp" id="farh"></span><span class="curr-temp">&deg</span></h1>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <label class="switched">
     <input type="checkbox" id="switch">
     <div class="slider"></div>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <h3><span class="hi-lo" id="forecastLow"></span> Low - <span class="hi-lo" id="forecastHigh"></span> High</h3>
    <p class="forecast" id="weatherInfo"></p>
```

Comment: Are you wanting it done with styles?  Or are you okay to manipulate the value before it is inserted into the HTML?

Comment: A little knowledge: you can check for negative values by check if it is < 0; you can get the value without the negative sign by using `Math.abs()`; the value you put in the call to `html()` is what is displayed on the page. With those bits of knowledge, try and figure out how you would solve the problem.

Comment: See [mcve] please

Comment: Talemyn I am okay with any options. The main problem I'm having is the HTML line where there is span class Hi-Lo, so it passes forecastLow followed by "low -" then passes forecastHigh. So if the value of forecastHigh is a negative number I end up with "-10 low - -5 high" what I would like is "(-10) Low - (-5) High

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function like this to format your Output:

```
function formatTemperature(value){
    if(value < 0)
        return "(" + value + ")";
    else
        return value;
};
```

and wrap your values calling this function, passing the values.

I've updated your snippet example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var long;
            var lat;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;

            var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=79b001616877b59c717616181ee219ec";

            $.getJSON(api, function(info) {
                var farh;
                var cels;
                var kelvin;
                var tempMin;
                var minTemp;
                var tempMax;
                var maxTemp;
                var tempMinC;
                var minTempC;
                var tempMaxC;
                var maxTempC;
                var strF = ("\u00B0'F'");
                var tempSwitch = false;
                kelvin = info.main.temp;
                farh = Math.round((kelvin) * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
                cels = Math.round(kelvin - 273);
                tempMinC = info.main.temp_min;
                minTempC = Math.round(tempMinC - 273);
                tempMaxC = info.main.temp_max;
                maxTempC = Math.round(tempMaxC - 273);
                tempMin = info.main.temp_min;
                minTemp = Math.round((tempMin) * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
                tempMax = info.main.temp_max;
                maxTemp = Math.round((tempMax) * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
                var city = info.name;
                var weatherInfo = info.weather[0].description;
                var forecastLow = minTemp;
                var forecastHigh = maxTemp;
                var forecastLowC = minTempC;
                var forecastHighC = maxTempC;
                var currCond = info.weather[0].icon;
              
                function formatTemperature(value){
                  if(value < 0)
                    return "(" + value + ")";
                  else
                    return value;
                }
              
                $('#farh').html(farh); 
                $('#city').html(city); 
                $('#weatherInfo').html(weatherInfo); 
                $('#forecastLow').html(forecastLow); 
                $('#forecastHigh').html(forecastHigh); 
                $('#currCond').html(currCond); 
                $('#switch').click(function() {
                    if (tempSwitch === false) {
                        $('#farh').html(formatTemperature(cels));
                        $('#forecastLow').html(formatTemperature(forecastLowC));
                        $('#forecastHigh').html(formatTemperature(forecastHighC));
                        tempSwitch = true;
                    } else {
                        $('#farh').html(formatTemperature(farh));
                        $('#forecastLow').html(formatTemperature(forecastLow));
                        $('#forecastHigh').html(formatTemperature(forecastHigh));
                        tempSwitch = false;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="weather-header" id="city"></h2>
    <h1><span class="curr-temp" id="farh"></span><span class="curr-temp">&deg</span></h1>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <label class="switched">
     <input type="checkbox" id="switch">
     <div class="slider"></div>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <h3><span class="hi-lo" id="forecastLow"></span> Low - <span class="hi-lo" id="forecastHigh"></span> High</h3>
    <p class="forecast" id="weatherInfo"></p>
```